# Junit test cases for a class that generates text content

Tags: junit

I have a class named EmailNotificationContentBuilder. As the name suggest the class is responsible to generate content for an email notification to be sent after a process ends. The notification basically tells whether the process was successful or not, the start time end time and the statuses of the child processes ( in tabular format ). I have following doubts regarding writing Junit test cases for this class:-

1. Is it required to have a Junit for this class? Since it generates textual content.
2. If yes then how can I assert the content generated by the class ? Some of the contents are represented in tabular format.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you want to make sure it does what it's supposed to do? If yes, then write a test. If you don't care if the code works fine or not, then don't write one.
2. This is the most typical thing a unit test does: test that the value returned by a method is correct. Get the String it returns, and check that it's what you expect it to be:

   ```
   @Test
   public void shouldReturnTabularData() {
       EmailNotificationContentBuilder builder = new EmailNotificationContentBuilder();
       String result = builder.build("some input");
       assertEquals("title1\ttitle2\nvalue1\tvalue2", result);
   }
   ```

Comment: What if it uses ApplicationContext to read messages from message.properties? It gets little complicated. Can't even use Mockito here.

Comment: If you posted code, it would be easier to explain how to test it, or to refactor it to make it testable. Without code, we can only guess.